# Azure Automation: Run PowerShell after AD user added

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-automation

I'm reviewing Azure Automation, but I couldn't find out if it is possible to run a PowerShell script whenever a new user is added to Active Directory? The scenario I'm researching is whenever a new Office365 account is added through admin.microsoft.com then I want to configure some email preferences for this user. I have my PowerShell script tested already (so these preferences should be set correctly), but now I'm trying to find out how exactly this script should be executed right after account is added.

Thanks,

Comment: When you say `Active Directory` do you mean OnPrem or Azure AD? If users are created OnPrem it would take time to replicate on AzureAD

Comment: I meant Azure AD

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the Azure AD Audit logs for new user creation. You can export the Diagnostic Settings (logs) to Azure Monitor (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-activity-logs-azure-monitor)).

The following is an idea but I never tried it myself:
In Azure Monitor -> Logs you can find for example this query:

[image]

Modify it according to your needs and create an alert rule. In the alert rule, you can set up an action group that triggers your automation account with the PowerShell script.